# I'm trying to make a request to get users, but error 404 occurs java spring

Tags: java, spring

```
package model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String login;

    private String password;
}
```

UserRepository

```
import model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    Optional<User> findByLogin(String login);
}
```

Controller

```
import dao.UserRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class RegistrationController {

    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    RegistrationController(UserRepository userRepository){
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/registrationUser")
    public String saveUser(@RequestBody User user){
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "User saved";
    }

    @GetMapping("/getAllUsers")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getUserByLogin/{login}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByLogin(@PathVariable String login){
        return userRepository.findByLogin(login)
                .map(user -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(user))
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=12345
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>diplomAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>diplomAPI</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm making a request `http://localhost:8080/main/getAllUsers` and the error is returned

```
{
"timestamp": "2024-02-06T08:05:07.441+00:00",
" status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/main/getAllUsers"
}
```

What could be the problem?

I added the `@ComponentScan` annotation, but it didn't solve anything. But the code looks as if there should be no errors in it.`

Comment: Misspell. I used http://localhost:8080/main/getAllUsers

Comment: Maybe you have to add the artefact name between the port and main

Comment: Please try `http://localhost:8080/diplomAPI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/main/getAllUsers`

Comment: I didn't understand it a bit. Can you tell me which artifact I should add?

Comment: The error remains.

Comment: Sorry misspelled the url can you give it a try with the edited one

Comment: BTW: The url for retrieving all users should simply be `/user`, `getByLogin` should be somethig like `/user?login={login}` and store a new user should also be `/user` with method POST

Comment: Your packages are a mess and therefor not picked up by the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, which is probably in yet another package. Unify your packages as recommended in the Spring Boot Reference guide (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.structuring-your-code).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` on the class of `RegistrationController`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@Controller` annotation on class level,
Spring use `ViewResolver` to find view which match to method's return value.

So if you want to return data, not view to client,
You have to use `@RestController` on TYPE level or use `@ResponseBody` on method level.

RestController.java

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public @interface RestController {

    /**
     * The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name,
     * to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.
     * @return the suggested component name, if any (or empty String otherwise)
     * @since 4.0.1
     */
    @AliasFor(annotation = Controller.class)
    String value() default "";

}
```

RestController annotation contains @Controller and @ResponseBody itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. At the DiplomApiApplication level, I have created packages for the repository, models, and controllers.